# Edit JSON Array in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, json

Is there are any way that can edit values inside json array in MS SQL? For example

```
A | B | Data
```

Where column 'Data' - is json array like

```
[{
        X: {
            X1: 'XXX',
            X2: 'XXXX'
        }
    }, {
        X: {
            X1: 'YYY',
            X2: 'YYYY'
        }
    }
]
```

How can i edit values of 'X1'? I did that with unfolding and folding json array, but i think this is expensive script. I tried indexing through array, but function json_modify cant take non string literals as path.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Can't check right now, I think it 2016. If you have answer no matter what version it for, please post it